# How do I solve this circle geometry problem?

Tags: geometry

How do I solve this circle geometry problem? It is question number 17 at this link: https://www.cusd80.com/cms/lib6/AZ01001175/Centricity/Domain/1520/Geo%20Circle%20Review.pdf

[image]

Comment: This problem looks broken to me. What is the difference between $\angle U$ (which is $109^\circ$) and $\measuredangle U$ (which is supposed to be unknown)? Also, I don’t believe $\angle TRS$ is uniquely determined from the given information ($RTUV$ may be a trapezium!) and also the information $\angle VRT=71^\circ$ is redundant as $RTUV$ is a cyclic quadrilateral... If you have access to whoever posted those problems, get back to them.

Comment: I agree with @StinkingBishop: if you fix points V, U and T you can still move point R along the circle without violating the requirements of the problem. But moving R will vary the angle TRS.

Answer (score 0):

Cnsidering comments and figure it seems $\angle RVU=90^o$. If this is correct then connect S to U. Clearly $\angle RSU=90^o$ and RSUV is rectangle and diametre RU bisects angles $VUT$ and $VRT$ , so:

$VU=RS$

$\overset{\large\frown}{RS}=\overset{\large\frown}{UV}=71^o$

$\overset{\large\frown}{UT}=71^o$

$\Rightarrow \overset{\large\frown}{ST}=180-2\times71=38^o$

finally:

$\angle SRT=\frac12 \cdot 38=19^o$